# Are these survey results about the approval ratings of the October 7 attacks by Hamas reliable?

Tags: israel, public-opinion, palestine, gaza

In a [news](https://apnews.com/article/israel-hamas-palestinians-opinion-poll-wartime-views-a0baade915619cd070b5393844bc4514) article published by AP news the following statements are made.

> Despite the devastation, 57% of respondents in Gaza and 82% in the West Bank believe Hamas was correct in launching the October attack, the poll indicated. A large majority believed Hamas’ claims that it acted to defend a major Islamic shrine in Jerusalem against Jewish extremists and win the release of Palestinian prisoners. Only 10% said they believed Hamas has committed war crimes, with a large majority saying they did not see videos showing the militants committing atrocities.

The survey was conducted by [the Palestinian Center for Policy and Survey Research](https://www.pcpsr.org/). I have no idea about the quality or affiliation of said institution. Are the reported numbers reliable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_Center_for_Policy_and_Survey_Research

Comment: Without details about how the poll was conducted this question will be impossible to answer.

Comment: A similar question about this survey was posted on [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/56639/7280)

Comment: I suggest that you look into incitement and indoctrination for Jihad in the Hamas run education system instead ... to get to what you probably want to get a sense of it may get you closer

Comment: Without delving into the poll's specifics, which an answer does quite well, there have been a number of news articles stating that, yes, Hamas gets a fair bit of *increased* support from West Bankers, *over* the PA.  And some of those articles even predated this poll so what it says doesn't seem to diverge all that much from previously reported sentiments.

Comment: How is this about Politics, rather than Statistics or Surveying or some such?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Is the PCPSR December 13 poll methodologically reliable?*
This poll has been much talked about and [the full report can be found at PCPSR page](https://www.pcpsr.org/en/node/963). The poll seems to have been carried out using appropriate procedures, as described in the report:

> The sample size of this poll is 1231 adults, of whom 750 were interviewed face to face in the West Bank and 481 in the Gaza Strip in 121 randomly selected locations. The sample is representative of the residents of the two areas. Due to the war in the Gaza Strip, we conducted interviews in the central and southern regions inside the selected sample homes, with the exception of one displaced area, where residents were interviewed in the shelter area where they had taken refuge. As for the northern Gaza Strip, residents were interviewed in 24 shelter locations, of which 20 belonged to UNRWA and 4 to governmental institutions. A total of 250 interviews were conducted in these shelters, and another 21 were conducted in the homes of relatives and friends of displaced people from the north. Despite the large representative sample, the margin of error for this poll is +/-4. The increase in the margin of error is due to the lack of precision regarding the number of residents who stayed in their homes, or in shelters, in the northern parts of the Gaza Strip which we did not sample.

There are obvious difficulties in conducting a survey and getting reliable answers in a war zone. Moreover, one should be always skeptical about the opinion polls in regions that are run by dictatorships or totalitarian regimes - [which is the case in Gaza](https://freedomhouse.org/country/gaza-strip/freedom-world/2023) - as the respondents risk to be punished for expressing disapproval of the authority. This is exacerbated by the war conditions, where one can be easily denied the basic life necessities, such as access to food and shelter.

*Does the poll correctly represent the attitudes in Gaza?*
The poll in question is very detailed, which permitted its findings to be cherry-picked to support both pro- and anti-Hamas views. E.g., while the support for Hamas is significant, it is still less than the majority of the population... even though majority does believe that Hamas would gain in strength as the result of the war:

> Support for Hamas increases in the West Bank from 12% three months ago to 44%; in the Gaza Strip support for Hamas rises from 38% three months ago to 42% today.

BUT

> 70% of West Bankers and half of Gazans expect Hamas to emerge
> victorious

There is also obvious discrepancy between the results in Gaza and the West Bank, less affected by the war:

> 75% of West Bankers and 38% of Gazans prefer Hamas to remain in
> control of the Gaza Strip after the war

*Denial of October 7 atrocities*
One of the key finding is the Gazans' refusal to believe that atrocities were committed by Hamas on October 7:

> 85% have not seen videos showing atrocities committed by Hamas against
> Israeli civilians on October 7, and only 7% say Hamas committed atrocities
> against Israeli civilians.

There is no reason to suspect this finding, although one cannot be sure of the exact numbers. Indeed, this attitude is widespread among Palestinians and their supporters in the Arab world and beyond. Just to give a few examples:

- A report from Egyptian Mada Masr site: [*Hamas document explains October 7 attack, calls on international community to end Israeli occupation*](https://www.madamasr.com/en/2024/01/22/news/u/hamas-document-explains-october-7-calls-on-international-community-end-to-israeli-occupation/)
- [*October 7 Fact Check*](https://www.oct7factcheck.com/index) - A site in English devoted to denial of Hamas atrocities
- [*Palestinian Ambassador To Nigeria Abdullah Abu Shawesh On The Eve Of ICJ Hearing: We Have A Feeling That Israel Might Behead And Burn The Corpses Of Palestinian Children It Stole From Gaza To Support Its Lies About October 7*](https://www.memri.org/tv/palestinian-ambassador-nigeria-abdullah-abu-shawesh-eve-icj-hearing-israel-behead-burn-corpses-children-gaza-lies-october-seven)

Gazans certainly have difficulty to accept the facts - firstly because they lack access to reliable information, but mostly because they don't have the luxury of taking a calm and detached view of the reality. If they do not believe that their own goodness, what else could they believe in, while facing everyday risk of getting killed?

Such a denial is harder to understand for somebody living in safety and prosperity - [the incompatibility of such support with western values is largely covered by the discussion around the similar views expressed on major US campuses](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/83225/38304).

**Related**
From [a more recent poll](https://www.dohainstitute.org/en/News/Pages/arab-public-opinion-about-the-israeli-war-on-gaza.aspx) by Qatar-based [Arab Center for Research and Policy Studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Center_for_Research_and_Policy_Studies), regarding the attitudes to the Gaza war in 16 Arab countries:

> While 67% of respondents reported that the military operation carried out by Hamas was a legitimate resistance operation, 19% reported that it was a somewhat flawed but legitimate resistance operation, and 3% said that it was a legitimate resistance operation that involved heinous or criminal acts, while 5% said it was an illegitimate operation.

Comment: I looked at the "October 7 fact check" site, and more than denial, I would say it primarily engages in what I might describe as "downplaying": relatively neutral presentations of facts, but generally while look for an angle that can be used to call them into question. For instance, they might mention that someone consistently reported sexual assaults, but suggest that this is undermined somewhat because someone else who was with them did not, and their topline conclusions are more "it's unclear what really happened" then "Hamas did nothing wrong."

Comment: Basically, trying to find angles by which Hamas can be absolved of systemic blame for any atrocities, while not necessarily denying that Hamas soldiers might have committed some. The "a few bad apples" treatment mixed with "fog of war."

Comment: @Obie2.0 The site is certainly aimed at a more intelligent/informed public, so it proposes a more nuanced view.

Comment: To @Obie2.0's point, I will note that the topline numbers say "85% haven't seen video, 7% say there were atrocities", which implies that these are two opposite answers (with the other 8% being 'not sure' or something) but when you get down into the details, it's actually two separate questions, and seeing video convinces 28% of the respondents overall (3->31%) and 33% of those in Gaza (8->41%) that there were such atrocities.  So there is definitely a slant to the reporting, even if the poll itself is fine.

Comment: @Bobson good point. Not having seen the video might be a consequence of war conditions - lack of access to internet or simply time. On the other hand, it might also reflect cognitive bias - unwilling to see something that might shake the one's worldview.

Comment: `only 7% say Hamas committed atrocities against Israeli civilians` The phrasing here can give respondents some wiggle room, e.g. depending on what status they assign to adult Israelis who have completed military service and could be called up to fight, but were living a normal civilian life on October 7th. Whatever their legal status, a surveyed Palestinian may not consider them in the same light. It's possible some Palestinians saw videos of attacks on Israeli civilians but thought they were valid targets for that reason.

Comment: `70% of West Bankers and half of Gazans expect Hamas to emerge victorious` - I wonder what definition of victory they're using. Does "victory" just mean "avoiding complete annihilation" here, or does it mean making actual political or geographic gains, or achieving some specific political goal?

Comment: @TKoL Israel's war aim is to completely annihilate Hamas (which is imo impossible), so if they fail at doing so, Hamas can claim victory.

Comment: @gerrit fair enough, if that's what the 70% of west bankers are betting on then I guess they have pretty reasonable goals. The survival of Hamas is pretty likely. Not much of an accomplishment but... if that's the criteria of victory, then they'll probably "win".

Comment: @TKoL 2006 Lebanon war is an example - lots of Lebanese died, the Lebanese prime minister cried on TV, and Hezbollah acknowledged that they erred in provoking the war. Still, Hezbollah declared victory and in Israel the war was widely considered a defeat - because the losses were judged unacceptable, the objectives were not achieved, and IDF couldn't stop Hezbollah from firing across the border (which they do nowadays as well, btw.)

Comment: What many people in the West don't understand is that universal social justice is a very recent concept and is not shared by the rest of the world. Until a few generations ago in the West, and in the rest of the world mostly even today, things were just or unjust depending on whether it benefits the in-group or the out-group. This means if an action gives more power to the in-group then anything and everything is justified. This is how the world used to work everywhere, and it still works in many cultures. The naiveté of not understanding this can be seen in many failed integration policies.

Comment: @vsz universal justice is a feature of monotheistic religions, notably encoded in the laws of Moses and the three religions stemming from them. The concept has been much abused throughout history, but I don't think the west has made any major innovations in this respect.