# Why do most Israeli Jews oppose humanitarian aid to Palestinians?

Tags: israel, public-opinion, palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, humanitarian-aid

[This recent survey](https://en.idi.org.il/articles/52976) found that a large majority of Jewish Israelis would prefer that Israel prevent humanitarian aid from reaching Gaza inhabitants:

> We asked our respondents for their opinion regarding the idea that Israel should allow the transfer of humanitarian aid to Gaza residents at this time, via international bodies that are not linked to Hamas or to UNRWA. A majority of Jewish respondents (68%) oppose the transfer of humanitarian aid even under these conditions, while a large majority of Arab respondents support it (85%).

Given that almost all Gaza residents are displaced by the war, humanitarian aid is the only way to survive for the vast majority of people in Gaza. Why do most Israeli Jews oppose humanitarian aid to Palestinians?

Comment: If you wanted your question answered by a poll, you'd have to ask that exact question, in a poll.  We have tons of evidence that framing, and the exact wording, matters highly in polls.  While I too find the poll extremely disturbing, and more evidence that food aid should be pushed into Gaza, *without asking Israel's opinion*, in the interest of avoiding mass starvation, that still doesn't mean *your* question can be answer on the basis of the wording in that poll.  VTC, opinion-based.  I will however upvote, because bringing to light this, again, extremely disturbing poll is of interest.

Comment: How likely are we to get honest answers in a poll like this? I mean on the death Q. Insert the quote about "Gaza sinking into the sea" or thereabout. Bibi said that Israel won't be paying for Palestinian welfare even after he closes the Rafah border. But that it would be other countries' problem to still do that. Countries which have be vetted by Israel too. So that's about as close to the truth as we'll get, government-wise, at least.

Comment: i.e. your chain of reasoning "no aid" -> "starve" is mostly valid, but whether a pollee runs through that exactly, rather than "screw them, let them figure it out" is unknowable.  Seems like a leading question.

Comment: There are a few additional facts that would help add context to this question. 1: Israel has declared war against Hamas. 2: Many countries have a law against providing aid and comfort to the enemy. Some just call it treason. 3: Hamas enjoys a plurality of support among Palestinians overall. With these 3 things, there is a lot more to consider with polling for information.  https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84338/are-these-survey-results-about-the-approval-ratings-of-the-october-7-attacks-by?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the [protests](https://www.jpost.com/israel-news/article-788568) around Kerem Shalom, which have been [going on](https://edition.cnn.com/videos/world/2024/01/29/exp-israeli-protesters-gaza-aid-nic-robertson-pkg-012912aseg1-cnni-world.cnn) for about a month at least, it's clear that a number of Israelis want to condition aid on Hamas freeing the hostages.

> These protests have occurred for several months. Early in February, dozens of protesters blocked the path of humanitarian aid trucks to Gaza at the Kerem Shalom crossing. In that instance, activists from the Tzav 9 movement stated that "the hundreds of aid and supply trucks for the terrorist organization Hamas will not enter through here today. We are proud and excited that the determination of this nation is winning. No aid will pass until the last of the hostages returns."

It would be interesting to know how many Israelis support this trade/conditioning, and [apparently](https://www.timesofisrael.com/almost-4-in-10-israelis-back-a-revival-of-jewish-settlements-in-gaza-poll-finds/) a TV poll asked precisely that.

> Also regarding the hostages, Channel 12 asked whether Israelis support halting humanitarian aid to Gaza until Hamas returns all the hostages it is holding. An overwhelming 72% said yes, while 21% said the aid should continue.

(Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a direct link to the poll, in that ToI article, for more details.)

[There is](https://www.timesofisrael.com/israelis-would-choose-to-destroy-hamas-over-releasing-hostages-poll-finds/) also a poll that found that Israelis prioritize eradicating Hamas over the return of the hostages, but not by a huge margin: 40% to 32%, somewhat higher among Jews: 47% to 25%. Perhaps more remotely related: the same Channel 12 poll found that 38% of Israelis [want](https://www.timesofisrael.com/almost-4-in-10-israelis-back-a-revival-of-jewish-settlements-in-gaza-poll-finds/) to resettle Gaza, 51% opposed that.

TBH, I strongly doubt any pollster would ask let alone publish a poll on your exact Q, i.e. how many Israelis want the Gazan's dead. Insofar, I wasn't even able to find a published poll on how many Israelis might want to see the Gazans deported, or even gone in mass. However a number of ministers [have](https://www.timesofisrael.com/israel-in-talks-with-congo-and-other-countries-on-gaza-voluntary-migration-plan/) expressed their view that there should be a "voluntary" migration program for Gazans, and Palestinians in general. And they even claimed that that has broad popular support:

> Smotrich [...] claim[ed] that over 70 percent of Israelis support the idea of “encouraging voluntary immigration” because “two million people [in Gaza] wake up every morning with the desire to destroy the State of Israel.”
>
> [...] Intelligence Minister Gila Gamliel told Zman that “voluntary migration is the best and most realistic program for the day after the fighting ends.” [...] On Tuesday, he presented his five-step plan at a conference in the Knesset (demobilization, establishing a security buffer zone, Israeli presence at the Rafah border crossing between Gaza and Egypt, voluntary emigration, and eradicating the terrorist atmosphere).

The recently published Netanyahu [plan](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/netanyahus-postwar-plan-gaza-reflects-difficult-balancing-act-experts-rcna140222) pretty much resembles that, without a mention of "voluntary emigration" though.

Answer (score 17):

Possibly, but not necessarily.

As mentioned in the comments, framing matters a great deal in polls, and many people, perhaps most, do not have fully formed sets of entirely consistent opinions. That is why, for instance, there have been polls of young people in which solid majorities simultaneously state there should be no billionaires, and that they want to *be* billionaires.

In the case mentioned in the question, from an objective perspective, continued humanitarian aid to the Gaza Strip is necessary to avoid widespread deaths. But that does not mean that all the poll respondents believe that. It's always risky to assume that people think logically and base their opinions on correct information.

Some may believe things that cause them to doubt that preventing the arrival of humanitarian aid would actually be harmful: for instance, they might believe that starvation in Gaza is greatly exaggerated, that any food aid would be taken by Hamas soldiers for their own use, or that the war will be over too soon for it to matter. They may not want Gazans to die, but might see any deaths as Hamas's fault for the October attacks/not surrendering. Or they just might not have thought very much about the logical connection between preventing food and water from arriving and starvation in the Gaza Strip (see the previous poll about billionaires for another example of this).

But some, indeed, probably *do* want Palestinians in Gaza to die. It might even be a large majority of the people who oppose humanitarian aid. It might even include some of those who do *not* oppose humanitarian aid. However, to know the actual percentage of Israeli Jews that actually want some or all Gazans to die, one would have to ask that *specific* question in a poll.

Comment: Well, we have certainly seen disturbingly relaxed attitudes on *some* posts here about Gaza *civilian* casualties.  Posts that attracted way too little censure, IMHO.  But, yes, otherwise, it is a great big leap to go from "we shouldn't be aiding them" to "we want them to die" in general.  Asking a "do you want them to die?" question would force poll respondents to think through what exactly they want and might/would probably result in a large shift of numbers though that, again, can't be known without asking that specific poll query, not its distant analogue in this question.